# Bootstrap 3.3.7 issue - Why is the !important attribute implemented?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, architecture

The bootstrap version 3.3.7 cause some major issues when using modals, functions etc.

If I want to use the class .hide for example, which is one of the declared classes in Bootstrap Css. The new version has set !important to that class, causing that the style never can be overwrite.
Same goes to the rest like .pull-right, .pull-left and .show.

The classes can be found in the Line: 6519 - 6528:

```css
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 
 */
 
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.hide {
  display: none!important;
}
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

---

I was playing around with some older versions of Bootstrap from some old webpages of mine. 
The bootstrap 2.2.2 looks like this in the Line: 6047 - 6059:

```css
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.2.2
 */
 
.pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

These classes can be used anywhere with out having problem of the structure to overwrite the style like hide or show.

I don't want to touch the bootstrap file if new versions comes out etc.

Why is it even set to !important?
Have someone got the same problems when building/ developing the web?

Comment: If you want it hidden why would you want to overwrite it? Also you could set your own styling if you wanted to

Comment: _“Why is it even set to !important?”_ - because otherwise you would not be able to use that class to hide elements that have the `display` property set to something else with a selector of higher specificity. `#foo { display:block; }` - now try and hide that by just adding the class `hide` to the element, if that class does not use !important

Comment: Read the dup question, this [article](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) and remember you can always override an !important by making a class with more specificity !important.

Comment: @Cbroe I understand. I should have edited the question and specify what my little problem was, more like; shouldn't Bootstrap.css and Bootstrap.js work togheter with the class .hide? Because the modal function are using "display: block;". I mean, if you want to use a standard structure. 
I just thought "if a developer is new to Bootstrap and, let's say, he/ she are using the modal function and sets .hide", then Modal will never open if you're not modifying the Css class. Since the show/hide thinking is a standard. But yea, you can use .fade to make it work.

Comment: @ZimSystem Yeah, I've should have specified the question in a more detailed way.